# Is there a <kbd> for the windows key?

Tags: support

I know we can use <kbd> to make keyboard short cuts like this <kbd>!</kbd> For example, if I wanted to explain how to open the Run prompt on Windows, which is the Windows key and R, how would this be done? (And for clarity, I mean the Windows key which is typically between <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>)?

Comment: If typing `ctrl` and `alt` isn't a problem, why is `Win` or `Windows`? It's not printed on the key, but just as clear. How about `shift` or `tab`? `backspace`? `return`? `left arrow`?

Comment: Because typing a key with Ctrl exists on my keyboard... But a key with win doesn't. Why else would I ask? :) please don't read my comment as rude, it is not meant to be :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Joey](https://superuser.com/users/2054/joey) has [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/501239/how-to-open-explorer-with-mouse-only/501248#comment599076_501248) of embedding the Windows logo image within the kbd tags. So

```
<kbd>![Windows Key][winlogo]</kbd>
```

Combined with a regular key, looks like:

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

Here's a better one that shows the 4 parts clearly:

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `<kbd>![Windows Key][newwinlogo]</kbd>`

Although FWIW I like the old one much better:

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `<kbd>![Windows Key][oldwinlogo]</kbd>`

Here are the images you have to use in your post's source code:

```
[winlogo]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfuw7.png
[newwinlogo]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Zit.png
[oldwinlogo]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0oPO.png
```

Comment: Err, "I like the old one much better" refers to me, not Sathya (although of course he may share my views!)

Comment: The only issue with the huge icon is that you can't really use it in a paragraph (because it'll increase the line height) or with other keys because it's too large.

Comment: @Karan indeed, I do!

Comment: @slhck: 16x16 vs 12x12, so I guess it might be possible to shrink it without losing too much detail (then again, maybe it'll end up looking just like the one Joey uses).

Comment: Hmmm, [not too nice on mobile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BI3sm.png) (or at least on some devices), nor for the few who have Imgur blocked at work.

Comment: Can someone please cleanup the excess white on `[newwinlogo]`

Answer (score 12):

Well, you could use a symbol that closely resembles a window, which is `SQUARED PLUS`, or Unicode: `U+229E`. It looks like this:

## ⊞

If it doesn't look like the Windows logo to you, you can also simply use <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> or <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd>. The benefit here is that everyone will know what you mean.

Comment: I call it the super key to be linux friendly.

Comment: Thanks. I had no problem typing windows but no key actually has the string "windows" and I was just curious. There isn't a key, but we don't care! :)

Comment: @DaveRook well Windows key don't have a string but you still call it **Windows/Win** key. ;)