# How do I make what I type look like keys on a keyboard?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Sometimes, when a key is mentioned, the key is shown with a box surrounding it. I don't know how to do that.

Could someone please help?

Comment: This is covered in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/denoting-keyboard-shortcuts-in-stack-exchange-posts

Comment: Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys/

Comment: Welcome to Super User (and Stack Exchange)!  A hopefully-handy-tip -- If you want to see how something was formatted, you can simply hit the Edit link that you'll find under any post.  Even as a new (or even anonymous) user, you have the ability to look at the original Markdown that was used to create the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>L</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> This?

Enclose the letter in `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`

Also works with [suitably sized images](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6048/is-there-a-kbd-for-the-windows-key)

Comment: Also works [when nested](https://superuser.com/a/1560646/432690).